# Cooling for an XPS 15 (L502x) laptop during Bitcoin Mining

Tags: mining-hardware, gpu-mining, mining-setup

I would like to know exactly where I should put my extra cooling fans around my laptop so that I can more efficiently cool while I mine bitcoins.  I realize this is not optimal at the moment, but before I invest in a rig I want to try it out with my laptop (but without overheating anything of course).  Is there a reason why my CPU is getting so hot while my GPU is comfortable even while I'm GPU mining?

Location like top-right, bottom-right, etc (w/r/t looking down on keyboard) is very helpful.

Also, what would be the best way to cool the BitForce Jalapeno?  Could I just use a simple fan in a well ventilated area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mining on a GPU, especially on less powerful ones like the ones found in laptops is highly inefficient. You can find out exactly how much you can potentially earn or lose from various Bitcoin calculators, like [mine for example](http://tpbitcalc.appspot.com/).

If you are worried about overheating your laptop and just want to test what mining is all about, you could also lower your hashrate, for example by introducing pauses in the miner. Most mining software should be supporting this feature, so you ought to look at the documentation.

Hardware specific question are probably best asked on different StackExchanges. You could just ask "where is my GPU on my laptop and how best to cool it?"
, which isn't Bitcoin-specific.

And if you want to ask about cooling of BitForce Jalapeno, why not post a separate question with that topic? The more specific question, the better.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to monitor your GPU temperature with [GPU Caps Viewer](http://www.ozone3d.net/gpu_caps_viewer/).

Bear in mind that different GPUs have different safe ranges for temperature, but in my understanding a general rule is that if the GPU fan isn't running full tilt then you aren't about to overheat your GPU.

Use the Windows Task Manager to view the CPU load. When mining with a GPU, it shouldn't be using more than a few % of your CPU cycles. I do remember over a year ago there was an issue with some mining software using 100% CPU; you may just need to run a different miner.

Comment: I actually use MSI to monitor my GPU.  My CPU doesn't seem to be running on full... it just gets hot.

Answer (score 0):

Efficiently aside, he probably doesn't have to pay for power. That said, it's ASIC land. GPU mining will be dead in under a year.